# what are my options for hosting a WCF service

Tags: web-hosting, web-services, wcf, iis

My company is building a system that will need to use user authentication and web services (WCF or ASMX whichever works, the differences are all confined to a tiny slice of code anyway) and our current hosting provider is somewhat "flaky". They are a low cost provided that seems to do Windows hosting as a second line service and explicitly doesn't support WCF and I've never gotten ASMX working exactly right.

Does anyone have experience with any reasonably priced web hosts that support WCF (or even ASMX)? I'm particularly interested in the setup and configuration being nice, direct and using well known system.

Comment: Sorry don't have experience with any providers, but on the technical front as long as ASP.NET is running correctly you shouldn't really be having any technical issues with a hosted ASMX (apart from the implementation of security/credentials - which is dependent on how the asmx is called and where accounts are stored).

Answer (score 1):

I've had a good experience so far with reliablesite.net (http://www.reliablesite.net/v3/index.asp).  Their support is snappy, and since you're talking a business here, you could use one of their semi dedicated accounts for pretty cheap and have a more reliable system.

Comment: Looks nice. If you are willing, what systems are you actually using there? Specifically, are you running any world visible WCF or ASMX services?

Comment: I'm going to be running both really soon (for a product I'm developing).  But supposedly they support both.  For a company such as you mention, I would really recommend a dedicated server though.  Any shared hosting really isn't good for anything other than brochure-ware sites.

Comment: At this point the server load will be very low and if it cranks up, that will be a problem we are happy to have and will pay for solving its self.

Comment: Gotcha.  Sounds like this is a start up type of thing and not a corporate type of thing like I thought you meant.